# Android :: Adding jar in libs vs importing a library

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, google-play-services

Curious to know what is the difference between adding a jar file in libs folder vs depending on a library project in eclipse.

For e.g. Google play library can be added in libs as a jar file whereas google doc says to import project and require main project to depend on play library project.

Does anybody know the difference between the two?

Comment: Never thought about it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to import a project as a library when you want to use the `Resources` from that project. Otherwise, you import it as a `jar`.